# How can one generate a queue system for php based web application in Windows for multiple requests/jobs?

Tags: php, transactions, queue

I want each form submission of my php application to run in a queue as each request takes considerable time and resources. I found out about [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues) which is kind of complete system for such tasks but unfortunately is Linux specific.
Additionally the email support is also needed to retrieve the jobs by their id.

What might be the existing tools for windows based php applications?
If not, how to achieve this manually using mysql and php?

Few hits were found on this e.g. [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-batch/index.html) but not actually getting from where to start.

Comment: "not availble with Windows support" cann you please elaborate on your findings?

Comment: edited question.

Comment: Does RabbitMQ provide the queuing style your after?

Comment: @NigelRen probabally, yes.

Comment: If your up for a challenge - try using Docker to install it, but simpler is just https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) should be what you're after.

It supports Windows, but you'll need to write some code to get it to do what you want.

Comment: It needs the server to be installed. Will it clash with my already working Windows IIS Service at localhost?

Comment: It shouldn't, if you know what you're doing. You can try finding a working example/online tutorial and follow it to get a better understanding of how RabbitMQ/message brokers work.